# How can I set the default radio button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the default radio button to the recurring gift. I have tried the following:

```
$(function() {
var $radios = $('input:radio[name=paytype]');
$radios.filter('[value=multi]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Please see complete HTML code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/h57sA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code works**, but you don't need filter. Same thing can be acheived using [**Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Use

```
 $('input:radio[name=paytype][value=multi]').prop('checked', true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/h57sA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is, you just needed to include `jQuery` into the jsfiddle: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzR77/)

Even though I do like Satpal's answer better than your solution. (same functionality, less syntax)